# How to define a custom name for <li> element in HTML?

Tags: html, list, html-lists

I want to define an ordered list, that looks like this:

```
3. Foo
   1. Foo
   2. Bar
3a. Bar
```

I already know I can use

```
<ol start=3></ol>
```

markup to skip items 1 and 2, but I don't know **how can I make the last element use "3a" as it's name**, without nesting another list like this: "3. a. Bar".

Is this even possible in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li class="newList">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
 </ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

.newList:before{
 content: counter(item) "a " ;
}

li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: counter(item) ;
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -2em;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzz6uaaL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot merge letters and numbers, seeing the [documentation of ol HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp)

> **Syntax**
>
> `<ol type="1|a|A|i|I">`

`|` means **or**, you can use only one in a time (I tryied `type="1a"` but doesn't works).